# Webpack-dev-server Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack-dev-server

Welcome,

I'm new to React and Node.js especially. I wanted to learn something about React and ended up struggling with Node.js. The problem is i cannot set a web-dev-server properly. Sorry if this questions seems trival although I haven't find a solution for hours.

Here it is:
**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: 'app/js/main.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }]
    }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "Github_profile_viewer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "BSD", 
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "5.8.*",
    "babel-loader": "5.3.*",
    "webpack": "1.12.*",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.10.*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^0.14,7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7"
  }
}
```

**http://localhost:8080/app/js/main.js**

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};

/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId])
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;

/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            exports: {},
/******/            id: moduleId,
/******/            loaded: false
/******/        };

/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.loaded = true;

/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }


/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;

/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;

/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";

/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    (function webpackMissingModule() { throw new Error("Cannot find module \"./src/index.js\""); }());


/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

I also receive such warrning when I try to establish webpack-dev-server:
[CMD Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmUqJ.jpg)

Alas I already `npm installed` that required module (at least it should be that way).

I have no idea what I have to do to make it works :(

Comment: What is the directory structure of your app? Make sure the entry point is in `./src/index.js`

Comment: The error in the picture says lodash is not found. Try `npm install --save lodash`

Comment: Thank you for your answers but they didn't help.

1. I cannot use npm install --save lodash, It results in error. Nevertheless I added lodash as dependency and devDependency in package.json file. When i run npn install it runs, but webpack-dev-server can't find it still. 

2. My file structure is fine for sure :(

Comment: Please include the file structure of your app.  List it from Root downward, just so we can validate your paths are correct

Comment: You may also find that your npm install didn't work correctly the first time, by the sounds of the CMD error `Cannot find module lodash/lang/isFunction` it sounds like the lodash library is missing some of its child dependencies.   Try running `npm cache clear` then deleteyour `node_modules` folder and run `npm install`, this may fix your issue

Comment: OK, problem solved. I reinstalled all node.js modules and the node.js itself. It finally worked after new installation. Maybe I was using outsated app. Anyways thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that lodash should be included via `npm install`, but webpack-dev-server can't find it:

[image: npm install]

Answer (score 0):

It's a cache error or something like that. A quick solution may be:

```
rm -rf node_modules
rm -rf ~/.npm
npm install -g npm
npm install
```